# Error al compilar Fortran: Symbol cannot have a type

Tags: fortran

```
PROGRAM suma

REAL n, suma, diferencia
INTEGER i 
    
suma=0 
WRITE(*,*)'Ingrese un valor para n:'
READ(*,*)n 
    
DO i=1,101
suma=suma+(1.+(i-1.)/10.)
END DO
    
diferencia=suma-n
    
WRITE(*,*)'La suma es:', suma 
WRITE(*,*)'La diferencia con n es:', diferencia 
    
END PROGRAM suma
```

Los errores:

> Error: Symbol ‘suma’ at (1) cannot have a type
>
> `main.f95:6:5:`
>
> ```
> 6 | suma=0
>   |     1
> Error: ‘suma’ at (1) is not a variable
> ```
>
> `main.f95:11:5:`
>
> ```
> 11 | suma=suma+(1.+(i-1.)/10.)
>    |     1
> Error: ‘suma’ at (1) is not a variable
> ```
>
> `main.f95:14:16:`
>
> ```
> 14 | diferencia=suma-n
>    |                1
> Error: Symbol at (1) is not appropriate for an expression
> ```
>
> `main.f95:16:30:`
>
> ```
> 16 | WRITE(*,*)'La suma es:', suma
>    |                              1
> Error: Symbol at (1) is not appropriate for an expression
> ```

¿Me ayudarían? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Tuviste que crear otro usuario?

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema es que el programa tiene el mismo nombre que la variable `suma`.
Eso produce una colisión porque el nombre de la función está en el namespace que se usa en el cuerpo de la función.
Cambia el nombre de la variable y el programa compilará sin problemas.

---

Para más información se puede consultar el [estándar de Fortran F2018](https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/18/18-007r1.pdf) epígrafes: 19.2 Identificadores globales, 19.3 Identificadores locales y 19.3.1.2 (traducción mía):

> En su entorno, un identificador local de una entidad de clase (1) [lo cual incluye variables con nombre] o clase (4) no será el mismo que un identificador global usado en ese entorno.

Este epígrafe incluye una serie de excepciones que no voy a describir aquí.